# Carrierwave and Dropzone with Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, nested-attributes, dropzone.js

I have been battling with this all day and can't seem to figure out the solution.

In my application, a user can create a Property and upload many photos for that property, as defined by these models:

**Property.rb:**

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

**Attachment.rb:**

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base        
    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
    validates_presence_of :photo

    belongs_to :property        
end
```

As you can see, Attachment uses Carrierwave uploader for uploading the picture.

This is the create method defined in my controller, very simple:

**properties_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @property = current_user.properties.build(property_params)

    if @property.save
        save_photos
        flash[:notice] = "Your property has been created."
        redirect_to @property
    else 
        flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong."
        render :new
    end
end
```

And these are the strong parameters and save photos methods:

```
def property_params
   params.require(:property).permit(:name, :price, :address, :department, :type_id, :description, attachment_attributes: [:id, :property_id, :photo])
end

def save_photos
   # Create Each Uploaded Photo
   params[:attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
      @attachments = @property.attachments.create!(:photo => photo)
   end
end
```

As of now, file uploading works like this without using Dropzone. However, when I want to integrate Dropzone into my form, this is where the problem arises.

I have added the **dropzone** class to my form, from the view:

**_form.html.haml**

```
= f.fields_for :attachments do |at|
   = f.file_field :photo, :multiple => true, name: "attachments[photo][]"
```

Now, on my dropzone configuration file:

**properties.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  // grap our upload form by its id
  $("#new_property").dropzone({
    // restrict image size to a maximum 1MB
    maxFilesize: 5,

    // changed the passed param to one accepted by our rails app
    paramName: "attachments[photo]",

    // show remove links on each image upload
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictDefaultMessage: "Arrastre sus fotos aqui.",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 5,
    maxFiles: 5,


     // The setting up of the dropzone
    init: function() {
      var myDropzone = this;

      // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
      this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        myDropzone.processQueue();
      });

      // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
      // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
      this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
        // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
        // Hide the success button or the complete form.
      });
      this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
        // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
        // Redirect user or notify of success.
      });
      this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
        // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
        // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
      });
  }




  });
});
```

This code includes configuration to work with the form in a way that the photos will only be uploaded when the whole form gets submitted, as explained in [this tutorial](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone).

So once dropzone is implemented, I can drop the files with no problems. However, when I try to upload the form, it seems it cannot recognize the photo files parameters. I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in PropertiesController#create  undefined method `[]'
>   for nil:NilClass 
>   on line: params[:attachments]['photo'].each do
>   |photo|

It seems that as soon as I add the dropzone, the parameters just vanish and become nil. I have tried toying with the *nameParam* attribute in the dropzone configuration, but all to no avail.

Help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: yes the nameParam is vanish, no matter what I change, I dont see the effect. All I got was the original nameParam file

Comment: Did you solve this @Andres

Answer (score 1):

Erm.. I know it's late but I have an answer for this.

your form name is `attachments[photo][]` right?

your dropzone should look like this:

```
paramName: attachments[photo]
uploadMultiple: true
```

The solution is in here:

```
def save_photos
   # Create Each Uploaded Photo
   params[:attachments]['photo'].each do |photo|
      @attachments = @property.attachments.create!(:photo => photo.pop)
   end
end
```

You just need to pop the last array value which contains the files. Since in dropzone, when you add `uploadMultiple: true` the output will be `[0, file1], [1, file2] and etc.` So `photo.pop` will get `[file1] [file2] etc.` and push to the database.

Comment: Hello Kris but the method pop removes the last element in an array and returns it. And what is doing is saving the file photo. no?